# Running an Excel Macro in Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks

I currently have an Excel Macro saved in the personal workbook that I would like to run when opening a file with the task scheduler. Right now I am able to get the workbook to open and then it cannot find the macro that it is trying to run. I am using the "/x MACRONAME" Argument to try and run the macro currently and I am afraid that I can't figure out the correct name. I have tried just using the macro's name and PERSONAL.XBLS! followed by the macro's name. I feel like I am missing something very obvious and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the `Workbook_Open` event to run the macro?

Comment: No, this does not work.

Comment: EDIT: I am able to get this to work, I guess the issue now is getting Access to export a macro-enabled Excel Workbook.

Comment: And solved by just using an xlsb workbook. Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't even think about approaching it from that angle.

Comment: You might find it easier (more flexibility) to have the task scheduler run a vbscript which open excel, loads your file, and runs the macro, then saves/closes everything.  E.g: http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html